# Generate UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

In one View I need about 50 `UIButton`s.

I would do it as 5x10
first line `UIButton`s started with A1, A2 and ....
Second line `UIButton`s started with B1, B2 and ....
....

how can I emplacement and generate the buttons.

Also after I did implement how I can call it in XCode! For example if I would create IF statement for A1 to A10, how can I deal with it.

Comment: I'd suggest storing this in some form of 2D array, otherwise this will be a huge pain keeping track of all the names.

Answer (score 3):

I will provide a logic for you.You can uniquely identify a button among 50 buttons is by the use tag property.
But this tag will accept only numbers so assign a logic to set tag property as numbers

For eg: your A1 fifth button will have tag value as 105

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        //Create Buttons here
        button.tag = ((i+1)*100)+(j+1);
    }
}
```

Now If you want to know which button clicked get the tag value by id

```
-(IBAction) buttonClick :(id)sender
{
   int tagValue = sender.tag;
   // You can split the tagValue to know which line the button is clicked
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your message. But the problem is for () doesn't create button 1 to 100! I need to product for example 10 UIButton all started with 'A' letter and the second letter with numbers. I mean the UIButton named: A1, A2, A3..... then B1, B2 .... so I would create the FOR to for example if int i = 1 then A1 = 1, if int i = 2 A1 = 1, A2 = 2 and so on!.... I'm not sure I could explain my meaning! sorry

Comment: I assume you want UIButtons with button titles A1,A2...A10 and so on for B,C,D,E. what for the if condition. Tell me clearly about the if conditions. Do u need to find out which button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Use a switch case:

```
- (IBAction) myMethod:(id)sender {
     UIButton *b = (UIButton*)sender;
     if (b == A1) { /* do something */ }
     if (b == A2) { /* do something */ }
     // etc.
}
```

Comment: This won't work. A switch statement can only contain constants.

Comment: @Denis, wow.  Brain Fart.  I had to go back and change some of my other answers.  I need more sleep.